# functions within objects causing an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, object

I am trying to finish a small js task, wrote the code but I am getting a syntax error.  Can you guys tell me what error is in it.?

The task is to create a new variable called myBalance that calls the askTeller function with a password argument, 1234.

```js
function Person(first,last,age) {
   this.firstname = first;
   this.lastname = last;
   this.age = age;
   var bankBalance = 7500;

   this.askTeller = function(pass) {
     if (pass == 1234) return bankBalance;
     else return "Wrong password.";
   };
}

var john = new Person('John','Smith',30);
/* the variable myBalance should access askTeller()
   with a password as an argument  */
var myBalance = this.askTeller.function(1234);
```

Comment: What line has the syntax error and what is the error?

Comment: Are you getting a *syntax error* or a different type of error?  As a note for the future: when you ask a question here, put the *exact* error message, don't just say "I get an error".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need this:

```
var myBalance = john.askTeller(1234);
```

The reason is you create `john` as a new Person. Now `john` has all the methods/properties that you create in the `Person` constructor, including `askTeller`.

Comment: Just to expand a little bit, the problem you are having is because of scope. When you declare "this.askTeller", you're adding that to the Person object, but the other parts of the application still don't know about it. So when you tried to call "this.askTeller" outside of the "john" person object, "this" was actually referring to the window (you can test this by doing a `console.log(this)` in your browsers dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

`askTeller` is a member of `Person`. So, you need a `Person` object in order to call the function. You already created one, `john`, so you just need to use `john.askTeller`.

```
var myBalance = john.askTeller(1234);
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to wjohnsto, you are creating a class with a function called `askTeller`, all you have to do is to create an instance to `Person` class and access its method.

`ClassObject.MethodName(Parameters)` in this manner.